# CLR Assembly with dll

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want assembly my dll in Ms sql server.
code dll here

```
  using System;
  using System.Data;
  using System.Data.SqlClient;
  using System.Data.SqlTypes;
  using Microsoft.SqlServer.Server;
  using System.IO;
  using System.IO.Compression;

 public class FileCompressCLR
{
    [Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlFunction(IsDeterministic = true, DataAccess =      DataAccessKind.None)]

//Загрузка файла в виде бинарника, на входе Полный путь к файлу
public static SqlBytes LoadFile(string FileName)
{
    FileStream file = new FileStream(FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);

    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    int sourcebyte = file.ReadByte();
    while (sourcebyte != -1)
    {
        ms.WriteByte((byte)sourcebyte);
        sourcebyte = file.ReadByte();
    }

    file.Close();
    return new SqlBytes(ms);
}

//Загрузка файла в виде бинарника с компрессией, на входе Полный путь к файлу
public static SqlBytes LoadCompressFile(string FileName)
{
    FileStream file = new FileStream(FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[file.Length];
    file.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    file.Close();

    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();

    DeflateStream compress = new DeflateStream(ms, CompressionMode.Compress, true);
    compress.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

    compress.Close();
    compress = null;

    return new SqlBytes(ms);
}

//Выгрузка файла в указанный источник
public static string SaveFile(string FileName, SqlBytes CompressedFile)
{
    if (CompressedFile.IsNull)
        return "Error";

    try
    {

        FileStream file = File.Create(FileName);

        int sourcebyte = CompressedFile.Stream.ReadByte();
        while (sourcebyte != -1)
        {
            file.WriteByte((byte)sourcebyte);
            sourcebyte = CompressedFile.Stream.ReadByte();
        }

        file.Close();
    }

    catch (Exception)
    {
        return "Error";
    }

    return "OK";
}

//Выгрузка файла в указанный источник с предварительной декомпрессией
public static string SaveDecompressFile(string FileName, SqlBytes CompressedFile)
{
    if (CompressedFile.IsNull)
    return "Error";

    DeflateStream decompress = new DeflateStream(CompressedFile.Stream, CompressionMode.Decompress, true);

    try
    {

        FileStream file = File.Create(FileName);

        int sourcebyte = decompress.ReadByte();
        while (sourcebyte != -1)
        {
            file.WriteByte((byte)sourcebyte);
            sourcebyte = decompress.ReadByte();
        }

        file.Close();
    }

    catch (Exception)
    {
        return "Error";
    }

    finally
    {
        decompress.Close();
        decompress = null;
    }    

    return "OK";
}
```

}

Then i write like that in SQl

```
    --Включаем выполнение пользовательских сборок
SP_CONFIGURE 'clr enabled', 1
GO
RECONFIGURE
GO

--Создаём тестовую БД для демострации
CREATE DATABASE TestDB
GO

--Модули базы данных (например, пользовательские функции или хранимые процедуры),
--которые используют контекст олицетворения, могут обращаться к ресурсам,
--находящимся вне базы данных.
ALTER DATABASE TestDB SET TRUSTWORTHY ON
GO

--Переходим в нашу БД
USE TestDB
GO
```

When i Execute  this

```
--Регистрируем сборку
**CREATE ASSEMBLY FileCompressCLR
FROM 'C:\CLR\FileCompressCLR.dll'
WITH PERMISSION_SET = UNSAFE;
GO**
```

i have mistake (create assembly for assembly failed because assembly is malformed or not a pure .net assembly Unverifiable PE Header/native stub).
What i must to do, for it all work, can your help me?

Answer (score 0):

FileCompressCLR should be marked as partial class.

All the SQLCLR class may it be UDF or CLR procedures needs to be partial class.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2kae45k(v=vs.90).aspx

Which version of SQL server you are using. There may be many restrictions as which Framework APIs are callable from UDF.

But it seems System.IO is supported. Try to change it to Partial class and see.

Hope it helps.

Note:

The libraries/namespaces supported by CLR integration in SQL Server are:

```
CustomMarshalers,
Microsoft.VisualBasic,
Microsoft.VisualC,
mscorlib,
System,
System.Configuration,
System.Data,
System.Data.OracleClient,
System.Data.SqlXml,
System.Deployment,
System.Security,
System.Transactions,
System.Web.Services,
System.Xml,
System.Core.dll,
System.Xml.Linq.dll,
```

The System.DirectoryServices namespace is not supported.